# Make gallery images show up one after one using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, css

I've got a gallery on one wordpress based site. The gallery images appear on the screen one after one, here is the code below.

```
$(".gallery-item").css({opacity:0});

$('.gallery-item').each(function(i) {

     $(this).delay(i * 300).animate({ opacity:1 }, 400);

});
```

It works fine but every now and then when I refresh/click on the gallery page, it seems all the images appear at once then disappear and the animate starts. Anyone knows why this is happening sometimes? Any fix for it please? Thanks.

(I used opacity:0 in CSS before, but it appeared the images wouldn't show up for some browsers, which make me to keep it in my jquery.)

Comment: does keeping opacity in css solve your problem?

Comment: I put the opacity:0 in CSS before, yes the above issue seemed to go away but some browsers wouldn't show images at all when I tested it, so I left it in jquery. Do you think opacity:0 was the cause for images disappear all together for some browsers?

Comment: It could be because of css loading at earlier than js. And it takes some time  for js to kick in

Comment: Any way to fix that eg to load this js before? Do you think it is better to put opacity:0 in CSS insteat? I worry about cross browser issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be a kind of hack, but you can try putting in css:

```
 .gallery-item {
     display: none;
  }
```

and then in js:

```
$(".gallery-item").show().css({opacity:0}).each(function(i) {

     $(this).delay(i * 300).animate({ opacity:1 }, 400);

})
```

or use:

```
.gallery-item {
     visibility: hidden;
  }

$(".gallery-item").each(function(i) {

     $(this).delay(i * 300).animate({ visibility: 'visible' }, 400);

})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I changed my code as above, but the animate doesn't work any more.

Comment: Thanks @Said Kholov , do you think this will be capable for cross browsers eg IE 7-11, chrome.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility here you go. You can use it in IE 4

Comment: Thanks. I tried your first solution (display: none;) the images wouldn't show up in IE. The second suggeation, all the images disappeared and wouldn't show up. Help:)

Comment: So far I found the first suggestion didn't work in IE 10 and IE 11, it seemed to be ok under IE9. Do you think display:block is better than opacity:0? Do you think some preload to load the whole site would help? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: display:none => removes the element from the page, and opacity just makes it invisible leaving the space. You can go with display block, if it suits your needs

Comment: Sorry typo problem, I meant display:none, it removes all the items all together for IE 10 and 11.

Comment: you can put opacity in css, and it won't work for IE7. For IE 8.0 use:
filter: alpha(opacity=xx)
filter: "alpha(opacity=xx)". I wouldn't care to much about IE7 honestly

Comment: I'm happy to use opacity:0 in css, it's ok if the animate function doesn't work for IE 7 and 8 as long as all the images show up on the page for all browsers especially IE with an opacity 0 in css and jquery add opacity 1, the reason I kept everything is jquery was because I need all the gallery images to show on the page for all browsers. Which one would you recommend the most for my case?